# Firemonkey Listview detect press location

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I'm using a `TListView` in Firemonkey. I'd like to able to use the `OnItemClick` event to serve two purposes:

1. toggle a checkbox image if the user clicks on the far left of the item
2. load some data about the listview item if the user clicks anywhere else.

Toggling the checkbox bitmap works easy using:

```
AItem.Objects.ImageObject.Visible := not AItem.Objects.ImageObject.Visible;
```

The problem is that I don't know how to go about only toggling the checkbox when the user presses the bitmap region.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that checking if the mouse is inside the `AItem.Objects.ImageObject.SrcRect` or a rectangle with origin on `PlaceOffset` might be the way. But cannot verify this since I don't have Delphi XE5.

Comment: That looks like the way to go. I tested by grabbing the X,Y coords on mouse down and I think that will work. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just add an onClick method to the checkbox? Or an onChange method

Comment: Don't think so, it's not an actual checkbox. The most direct access I have to it is the AItem.Objects.ImageObject which if I remember right didn't have events for click or change.

Comment: Can you post the code how you create the listview items? Do you add them manually or by code? I've made custom listbox items where you can add a button or whatever you want and you can handle the components normally too so the button has an onclick method